# Excel Power Query import of SharePoint List data changes date/time values

Tags: excel, datetime, sharepoint, powerquery

I have an Excel file that pulls data from a SharePoint list using Power Query. When I compare the date field values in SharePoint e.g. 4/30/20 8 PM they uniformly appear as 5/1/20 1 AM in the Power Query view.  This results in the data being shown in the wrong time periods in pivots, etc. Any ideas what is happening? I am not a DBA or SysAdmin so your patience with this question is appreciated! Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the Datatype of your Date(Time) Column and the query Step like "Change Types".
If there is a little globe left in your column header than the Data-Type is set to Date-Time-Zone.

Change the type to "normal" date/time.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, Chris. The data is coming over from SharePoint as text and already plus five hours from the original values. Converting it to Date/Time preserves the wrong data. I think I might try a custom date/time function to reset it to the "original" values..

Comment: Hello Andy, you can try to set the columntype to a Date/Time region which will subtract the 5 hours in PowerQuery ;-)

Comment: That worked! I changed the columntype to DateTimeTimezone and then used the Local Time option.

Comment: Top! Maybe you can vote the answer and set it to solved.